# Scrapy and content updated with JavaScript

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to scrape (headliner, date, time) a local music venue site: http://www.bluebirdtheater.net/events

I've used scrapy and I've successfully scraped what's on the site. However there's a load more button. I've seen other solutions where the load more button returns a POST response in rendered html that can be scraped.

With the browser inspector I see that this site calls a get method: http://www.bluebirdtheater.net/events/events_ajax/40

I used scrapy to call url to crawl but the response is in unreadable for scrapy (JavaScript? Unrendered DOM? Can anyone tell me what it is? I'm curious.) Can I still use a scrapy-only approach?

I've seen people use Selenium to physically click the more button and load all the data, and then scrape it.

Comment: The string needs to be escaped. Its basically a text file.

Comment: Thanks! I can continue working on a scrapy-only approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel sorry for doing this but heres a quick fix that will replace all spaces and new lines and backslashes.

```
print s.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\\','')
```

Comment: I had to use double escapes to complete remove the space and new lines but I get the gist. Thanks for your help!

 .replace('\\n', '').replace('\\t', '').

Comment: Whichever works for you. You can close the question by accepting the answer.